# Making a bash script switch to interactive mode and give a prompt

Tags: bash

I am writing a training tool, it is written in bash to teach bash/unix.

I want a script to run to set things up, then to hand control to the user. 
I want it to be easily runnable by typing `./script-name`

How do I do this?

I.E.

- User types: `tutorial/run`
- The run-tutorial script sets things up.
- The user is presented with a task. (this bit works)
- The command prompt is returned, with the shell still configured.

Currently it will work if I type `. tutorial/bashrc`

Comment: Some example workflow would really help here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are several options:

- You start script in the same shell, using `source` or `.`;
- You start a new shell but with your script as a initialization script:

The first is obvious; I write a little bit more details about the second.

For that, you use `--init-file` option:

```
bash --init-file my-init-script
```

You can even use this option in the shebang line:

```
#!/bin/bash --init-file
```

And then you start you script as always:

```
./script-name
```

Example:

```
$ cat ./script-name
#!/bin/bash --init-file
echo Setting session up
PS1='.\$ '
A=10
$ ./script-name
Setting session up
.$ echo $A
10
.$ exit
$ echo $A

$
```

As you can see, the script has made the environment for the user and then has given him the prompt.

Comment: `--init-file` with nothing following it works. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to detect which script is running when using this trick? On my Mac running with just --init-file causes $0 to expand to "/bin/bash"

Answer (score 0):

Try making it an alias in your ~/.bashrc file. Add this to the bottom of ~/.bashrc:

```
alias tutorial='. tutorial/bashrc'
```

Then close and re-open your terminal, or type `. ~/.bashrc` to re-source it.

To use this alias, simply call `tutorial`, and that will automatically get replaced with its alias, as though you had called `. tutorial/bashrc`.